# How can i give a drop down to a cell of a table using aggrid in strealite app using python?

Tags: python, ag-grid, web-frontend, streamlit

How can i add a drop down to a cell of a table created with or without using aggird inside a streamlite environment (python). Can somebody help on this.
I need a drop down as "Long" or "Short" in the "Long/Short" column of the table rather than a manual text input. I've been struggling for hours, can somebody help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Long/short column without dropdown]

Comment: How did you create that table?

Comment: By creating a dataframe and inserting it into Agrid.

Answer (score 0):

I have not find a way to do it with AgGrid. However, why don't you try using a selectbox like the one you are using with "Number of cells"? Catch the values in the column and then pass those values to the selectbox, like:

```
filter_list = list(df["Long_Short"].unique())
selector = st.selectbox("Long_Short", filter_list)
```

Then place the selector whereever you need it. Remember to filter the df with the selected values, like:

```
df = df[df.Long_Short == selector]
```

Hope it helps